# JOOQ: Dynamic join conditions

Tags: java, jooq

I would like to create **conditions** from this **select** in JOOQ. Because in my case I want to declare a dynamic query and check if TABLE_C.FIELDC contains "foo" only when I need...

**Example**:

```
create.select().from(TABLE_A).join(TABLE_B).onKey(Keys.FK_TABLEA_TABLEB)
                    .join(TABLE_C).onKey(Keys.FK_TABLEB_TABLEC)
                    .where(TABLE_C.FIELDC.containsIgnoreCase("foo");
```

**to:**

```
SelectFinalStep select = create.select().from(TABLEA);

if (isFooSearched) { 
   query.addCondition( <JOIN> and <CONTAINS> like first example) 
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what the dynamic part should be here. I suggest editing the question with some details. What's the desired SQL query when `mycheck` is `true` / `false`? The more complete your question, the better the answer...

Comment: cant you do `select.where` and `select.join` in `if`??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this:

#### Using implicit joins

In relatively simple cases, when the optional join follows a to-one relationship, you may be able to use an [implicit join](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/) (if you're using the code generator):

```java
create.select()
      .from(TABLE_A)
      .join(TABLE_B).onKey(Keys.FK_TABLEA_TABLEB)
      .where(isFooSearched
        ? TABLE_B.tableC().FIELDC.containsIgnoreCase("foo")
        : noCondition())
      .fetch();
```

#### Using SEMI JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, which makes dynamic SQL much easier

```java
create.select()
      .from(TABLE_A)
      .where(
          isFooSearched
        ? TABLE_A.TABLE_B_ID.in(
              select(TABLE_B.ID)
             .from(TABLE_B)
             .join(TABLE_C).onKey(FK_TABLEB_TABLEC)
             .where(TABLE_C.FIELDC.containsIgnoreCase("foo"))
          )
        : trueCondition())
      .fetch();
```

Note that a semi join is also more formally correct in this case than an inner join, as you will not get any duplicate rows on `TABLE_A` for any matches in to-many relationships (removing them with `DISTINCT` might be wrong and certainly is inefficient).

Side-note: Not all databases recognise semi-joins in `EXISTS` or `IN` syntax, and may thus not optimally run this statement, compared to a `JOIN` based solution.

#### Using INNER JOIN as you asked for

```java
// I'm assuming DISTINCT is required here, as you
// - are not interested in TABLE_B and TABLE_C results (semi join semantics)
// - do not want any duplicate TABLE_A values
create.selectDistinct(TABLE_A.fields())
      .from(
          isFooSearched
        ? TABLE_A
             .join(TABLE_B).onKey(FK_TABLEA_TABLEB)
             .join(TABLE_C).onKey(FK_TABLEB_TABLEC)
          )
        : TABLE_A)
      .where(
          isFooSearched
        ? TABLE_C.FIELDC.containsIgnoreCase("foo")
        : trueCondition())
      .fetch();
```

I've mad a few assumptions here, including the fact that `DISTINCT` usage could be correct on your joined variant of the query, but it is hurting you (probably) on your "default" query variant, so perhaps, shoe horning this into a single dynamic query might be overkill.

Thus...

#### Using two different queries

For my taste, the two queries are simple enough to allow for some duplication and simply run two different queries depending on the flag:

```java
if (isFooSearched)
    create.select().from(TABLE_A) /* joins or semi joins here */ .fetch();
else
    create.select().from(TABLE_A).fetch();
```

#### Side note

All solutions are assuming you have these static imports in your code:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Comment: Thank you Lukas! You are right, the two queries are simple. But unfortunatelly I haven't only fooParam to check. (And Thank you for your great work! Jooq is awesome!)

Comment: @Luigi1982: Thanks for your nice words. Sure, I was "afraid" that your example might be simplified, so I guess the semi-join solution fits best here...